# Bootstrap 3 Flat.theme problem after Domino 12 upgrade

Tags: bootstrap-4, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm developing xpages by using Bootstrap (Xpages Properties Application Theme "Bootstrap3.2.0_flat")

After the upgrade Domino 12 console give me error when i open xsp pages. i changed xsp Application theme to Bootstrap3 but give the same error

```
  HTTP JVM: getThemeFromBundle filename: com/ibm/xsp/theme/bootstrap/themes/Bootstrap3_flat.theme
  HTTP JVM: Inside PageRendered.java line 348 *********************
  HTTP JVM: Inside PageRendered.java line 348 *********************
```

I cant change Application theme to  Bootstrap 4 because responsive design Left Menu converting to static on the left and body viewpanel etc going to under to page like attached image.

How to solve Domino console error or bootstrap 4 design Left menu problem
[image: Bootstrap 4 Responsive design Left Menu problem screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The excessive console logging is a tracked bug on HCL’s side that should be fixed in a future version: https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0091023 . Are there problems on the page with the Bootstrap 3 theme beyond the console logging? If so, and it’s a clear difference in V12 and V11, that will likely also be a matter for support.

As for the Bootstrap 4 layout trouble, a lot could be going into that, particularly if you’re using custom styles. That said, you could try disabling resource aggregation, which is another one of the known bugs in V12’s Bootstrap: https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0091444 . The console logs will continue in Bootstrap 4 regardless.